# how zernike moments masks are computed for image edge detection?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to detect image edges based on the subpixel zernike moments masks method , but I can't find the same results of the masks ( A00, A20 and A11 ) when evaluating the integral as it is mentioned in the article.

so does anyone have ever worked with this technique, I want to be able to reproduce these masks so I can compute others with different order n.

when I compute the double integral over x and y , I get absolutely different values and I can't figure out how they came up with these masks

[the polynomials that we use to evaluate the double integral of x and y over each pixel of a 5*5 disk , note that x et y are between -1 and 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK1Nu.png)

[The masks used for edge detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY7A2.png)